# Hide AJAX info from Firebug, how? (with a working example site)

Tags: ajax, console

OK, I know this question has been asked so many times.

But there's this website developed with AJAX (not with jQuery/MooTools/...), which hides AJAX info COMPLETELY from Firebug console (except for some cookies).

It is in Chinese, the official blog of a social network website.
Mostly you guys can't read it, just click on the menu and pay attention to the console.

Here it goes..

http://qzone.qzone.qq.com

I'm wondering how they did that?
Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Look at this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223319/how-to-hide-ajax-requests-from-firebug-console