# How to hide ajax requests from firebug console?

Tags: ajax, browser, firebug

How to hide ajax requests from firebug console or anything that shows ajax calls ?

Comment: Why? For your own convenience? Or as a "security" feature?

Comment: "For a security purpose." If you are thinking to protect yourself from hackers this way, that won't work. You cannot hide the browser's activities from the user that is running that browser. Even if you can convince the user not to look (and 99% of users won't care about Firebug) you must not rely on that for security-relevant things.

Comment: @NikhilM, Hmm, why the firebug console specifically? There are many other sniffers besides firebug, e.g. Wireshark etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) calls. JSONP calls are not real ajax requests (because they don't use `XMLHttpRequest` object, and they simply inject a script tag into the DOM). But they won't be shown in Firebug.

Comment: Firebug would show them in the "Net" tab (where it shows images, css, and so on), no?

Comment: Yeah, still you can track it in *Net* tabs.

Comment: JSONP is not possible to implement in this stage as i have covered a lot with this project. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Nope, just one thing, and that is, even Google hasn't done such a thing. Therefore, you may search for other patterns of securing your website. :)

Comment: could JASONP might be vulnerable to attacks?

Answer (score 13):

Please, call this function after ajax success or fail:

```
$('.result').load('testtemplateboth/testpagetpl');
clearconsole();

function clearconsole() { 
  console.log(window.console);
  if(window.console || window.console.firebug) {
   console.clear();
  }
}
```

OR

```
$('.log').ajaxComplete(function() { 
  clearconsole();
  $(this).text('Triggered ajaxComplete handler.');
});

function clearconsole() { 
  console.log(window.console);
  if(window.console || window.console.firebug) {
   console.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: Still it will be visible in Net tab

Comment: This would also clear the rest of debug info. I am expecting, the asker just wants to remove extra noise from console.

Answer (score 8):

As described here (https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel), you can set it in about:config tab, changing the extensions.firebug.showXMLHttpRequests value.

Answer (score 5):

Use a binary websocket.

Although some browsers still allow users 'inspect' the contents of websocket packets in some cases, this is generally restricted to text-only websockets and a lot more difficult for binary data... and most definitely will not show up in the console.

This is the approach that Livereload (http://livereload.com/) uses to avoid spamming the console with ajax requests that make using the console for real debugging meaningful.

Obviously as the other posts in this thread have stated you *cannot* prevent someone from actually catching requests using tools such as Wireshark; but arguably a binary web socket would discourage 90% of the casual tampering that you might get with standard ajax requests.

Comment: Up for clarifying it's not possible but it will discourage most people.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried jQuery but it always used normal ajax calls. According to the docs: *requests with "JSONP" or "script" dataType and "GET" type should result "script" transport mode*. It works this way:

**Client side**:

```
var h = $('head')[0];
var e = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
e.src = "/c.php?getRefresh=1"+("&_="+(+new Date()));
e.onload = function(){
    //script from server executed       
    h.removeChild(e);
}
h.appendChild(e);
```

**Server side**:

```
if(isset($_GET['getRefresh'])){
    header("Content-Type: text/javascript");
    die("console.log('OK');");
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach but just to be sure: it removes the script from the header and re-adds it after the request. The server spits out a new header and just sends an OK to the debugger. However how is the getRefreshed prevented from being listed in the console anyway? Did anyone test this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be able to completely hide calls from any sniffing software due to the fact that some sniffing software packages work on a very low level (so low you can't actually get there from browser / code).

If you want to mask a call (e.g. hide where the call goes) you can send it to a server of your own and then the server can make the call itself (using some masked commands).

Like calling http://myserver.com/doCommand?command=cmd1&parameter1=param1&parameter2=param2

And the server can have the logic that will read the command and parameters, execute them and then report back with the results. Anyway the call between the client (browser) and your server can be caught by the sniffing software.

It is much like a proxy. The client can see what goes to the proxy but it will not know what happens next.

Anyway it feels a bit as if you have a problem with the architecture itself after you are going after masking calls from the caller and not the outer world.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Saeed was saying with JSONP, you could change the source of an image/file/script "src" attribute. The server will send the request when it changes, thus making it possible to communicate with the server. I haven't tried this but I'm looking at implementing it for something myself.