# how to hide in console (e.g. firebug) any get/post url using by ajax

Tags: javascript, security, jquery, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to hide ajax requests from firebug console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223319/how-to-hide-ajax-requests-from-firebug-console)

I would like to use jquery $.get function but when its triggered in console (firebug) everyone can see params I'm sending in this url. Is it any way to encrypt or hide them?

This hiding or encrypting method should be executed in some client side code, otherwise my ajax looses any sense...

I have found some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223319/how-to-hide-ajax-requests-from-firebug-console) but is there a better way?

Comment: If you want to prevent people seeing parameters you're sending over the wire, then don't use GET. Use POST, and consider running it over HTTPS as well. Firebug isn't the only way to peek at what the web browser is doing.

Comment: What is the sense of your Ajax?

Comment: love and sensibility what elese?!

Comment: Data that's on a browser can always be viewed by the user, by some means. Web security is about 1) securing the server and 2) securing the data transfer between users and the server (this is done via https)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible mate.

And the fact that you want to encrypt your parameters client side tells me you do not understand the fundamentals of encryption.

The best you can do, is during your AJAX request, find the return "parameter" in your "whatever.php" file, then use a hashing algorithm on it.

Comment: I don't want, just asking what is possible to do about this... thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

As Dan Kanze said, not really possible. Even if you somehow manage to get Firebug not to record it, I'll just use Chrome or IE. Or third party tools like Fiddler or HttpWatch.

If you really want to hide something from all those tools, use WebSockets, but that still doesn't prevent me from putting a breakpoint in your JavaScript code and checking all the parameters. In short, on the web, you can't really hide those things.