# how to safe/hide json data in firebug like facebook

Tags: json, jquery

whenever, i request to server using jQuery-ajax for retrieve data that is shows in firebug so that is unsafe or hackable.
even facebook and google+ hide their json data, but how?

Comment: Here is a possible answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8223578/1990528)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a library like [crypto-js](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#Ciphers) to encrypt all data that is sent to and from the server. However, most of the time, that is an overkill when you already use https (since you should make your application hack resistant via server side validation and safety is ensured by the real encryption offered by https).