# How Can I hide the ajax post parameter in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, security, post

Is there any way to hide the parameter that I send via post method using the Encoding or any other methods. Because Its roughly show my password in console and If I use Firebug with console Export It send my console log to any server we want show my password can leak through this.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223319/how-to-hide-ajax-requests-from-firebug-console

Answer (score 1):

Firebug can't do this, but you can use the `console.clear();` after ajax is completed for an empty console.
Also you can use a way to encrypt the password that you sent like md5() function.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Firebug can't do this. However, there is a very useful Firefox extension, in the spirit of Firebug, called [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/). This should be able to do what you want.

Comment: Instead adding external plugins. I ask a way to hide data via coding in client side or serverside

Answer (score 0):

No.

It would be up to you to process the output of ConsoleExport when it is received on the target server, to mask sensitive information (passwords and others). (Also it would make sense to connect to that server using SSL.)

A filtering feature in ConsoleExport might be a good idea but there is no such option at present.