# Secure headers is in ajax jquery request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have following ajax call and I am sending GET request with the header Authorization for security purpose.

```js
$.ajax({ //actually approve or reject the promotion
            url: "/api/testapi/",
            type: "GET",
            beforeSend: function (request)
            {
                request.setRequestHeader("Authorization","123456789");
            },
            data: JSON.stringify({
               
                promotionId: 1
            }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
               console.log(data)
            },
            error: function (xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {                
                console.log('xhRequest: ' + xhRequest + "\n");
                console.log('ErrorText: ' + ErrorText + "\n");
                console.log('thrownError: ' + thrownError + "\n");
            }
        });
```

But, when I send the call the value of Authorization can be easily seen by the Network Tab in the developer tools

[image]

For security purpose I need to hide this value.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: There is no way to hide any information given in a request. The token should be time-limited anyway. If you need high security, reduce the lifetime of the token before it must be re-issued.

Comment: Authorization in header is always used in some secure mechanism， not means that the request is secure

Comment: You can read [here][1] info about it.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223319/how-to-hide-ajax-requests-from-firebug-console