# disabling user console php output

Tags: javascript, php, console, console.log

I don't want to show GET commands (php script execution) showing in user console (Image attached). But don't know where to start & what to search exactly.

[image]

any help.

Answer (score 0):

i think what you need is `console.clear();`.

Comment: Well, console.clear(); removed other warnings (security) but it didn't worked for php scripts loading on page load. @RohitGupta - i don't want to display to anyone what inputs i'am using with specific scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested but it looks like your javascript is selling you out. I found this site which seems to allege catching javascript console output.

```
(function() {
    try {
        var $_console$$ = console;
        Object.defineProperty(window, "console", {
            get: function() {
                if ($_console$$._commandLineAPI)
                    throw "For Security Reasons - The script console is disabled for this site.";
                return $_console$$
            },
            set: function($val$$) {
                $_console$$ = $val$$
            }
        })
    } catch ($ignore$$) {
    }
})();
```

Sources: 
https://davidwalsh.name/disable-console ; http://pastebin.com/Lx5gjXsA

Comment: Sorry Steve, It didn't worked. (may be i'am using with wrong method). I tried placing this code inside head tags & inside body (before closing tag). But nothing worked.

Comment: Yes Steve. I am using php scripts to create array for autocomplete options on page load.

Comment: Well, i guess i found half soloution in following link over stackoverflow. Now only (Net) tab where scripts are showing values. Console tab is clear of all requests. "http://stackoverflow.com/a/9064158/3124743"